# how to open ms access database in android smartphone?

Tags: android

I have created application software in vb 6 long year back which accessing database from Ms access in my pc. Now I am looking for put that Ms access database in my android phone and view it. How to do that?

Comment: Export all the tables in CSV. Then reimport them into SQLite.

Comment: Thx for replying to my post . I really don't know what is csv.

Comment: CSV == Comma Separated Value....

Comment: Access knows it. And also any decent SQLite manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there are some definitions to understand here, namely database, software, and operating system. Access is two-fold as it combines a Front-End GUI management system with a Back-End database engine, Jet/ACE.

Ms Access as the software program is strictly a Windows PC software. Jet/ACE database server is strictly a Windows PC technology. So, neither component of Access can run in any other operating system including Mac, Linux, iOS, and Android. Now with that said, there may be private developer solutions listed on Google Play or Chrome web store which are not Microsoft products.

Therefore, some type of conversion and development is warranted in order to run your Access database content on Android. One such route mentioned in the comments includes [SQLlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) (which is like Access as a file server database or database that exists as individual files) claimed to be the most widely deployed database.

In order to do this, you need to do the following:

1. Download the free SQLlite for your computer AND as an app for your Android device.
2. Then you must export your database tables into popular data flatfile formats (csv, txt, xml).
3. Next, you need to import such data into SQLlite either with some type of management console (Firefox browser has a great plugin [Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)) or with code (Python maintains a built-in [SQLlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module) and import/append data from aforementioned data types. In fact with code you can directly connect to Jet/ACE engine via ODBC to extract database content and then migrate it to SQLlite without need of csv, txt, xml import/export route.
4. Connect your mobile device to your computer.
5. Transfer the sqllite file by simply moving files over between folders.

Other considerations is to run your Access as a web database in [Office365](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/a/Building-An-Access-Database-In-Office-365.htm) and log in via your Android over the web. Alternatively, export your Access database to server level database system (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) that runs over the web and then download the corresponding system app to view and manage content or build your own app to connect. Same above route with data file export or coding will convert between Access and any other system.

Comment: Thx parfait for such a brief explanation and your valuable time given to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I use the HandDBase app for my Android.  First you need to download their desktop software which will convert the MS Access tables you want into their own format.  Then I synch the recently converted tables to the HandDBase app and I'm good to go.  It is a two step process but also allows for encryption which makes me feel more comfortable as I'm not really great with SQL and am afraid my information might be vulnerable somewhere.

Link: http://www.ddhsoftware.com/handbase.html

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty old, but you can give my application a try (just incase if you missed, I'm the owner)... You can check it out at
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev404.dbviewer

The app is still in its initial stages though, but was worth a try for a lot of users.