# Use MS Access form on a mobile device

Tags: android, ms-access

I'm going to a robotics competition (FRC) in which we're supposed to "scout" other robots' and see how they perform. My database consists of the number of points they get for each category. I made a form to enter in the data. There are six teams, and I wanted to use six android phones or tablets for data entry.

**Is there a way to open the form and enter data in on a mobile device, and then transfer the records to a master computer?**

P.S. At the competition we would not have an internet connection, so the only data transfer methods would be USB, Bluetooth, or LAN.

Thanks

EDIT: I figured it out. Instead of using an access form, i'm creating an android app that simply allows you to enter the data in, and export the data as a csv to use in a database. I'll try and make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open ms access database in android smartphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180975/how-to-open-ms-access-database-in-android-smartphone)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to "run" MS Access application on any iOS, Android or WinCE device is using remote desktop. Enterprise solutions like Citrix would be better. You will need a server in local network, which can support the terminal clients and install on each device RDP terminal client or Citrix client. Access application in fact works on the server, mobile device shows the screen and allows to interact with application.