# Android Studio List View

Tags: android, listview, external-data-source

I would like to set up my code where when I click a line in my list view it returns text from a text file (from notepad or Access). Is this possible or will it need to be a different format.

This is what code I have so far, I believe it should be just one or two lines of code that will pull from a file. Here is my Main Activity Code:
`

```
Toolbar toolbar;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Materials));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MaterialName", listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Here is my Second Activity Code:

```
`
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    material = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) {
        mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("MaterialName"));
        if(mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("4140")){
            //how do I get it to return the information from a text file
        }
    }

}`
```

After looking through the links in the Answers my Second Activity now looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    BufferedReader reader = null;

   try {
       reader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("4140.txt")));

       String mLine;
       while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           text.append(mLine);
           text.append('\n');
       }
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error reading file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       if (reader != null) {
       try {
           reader.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {

       }
    }

    TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    output.setText((CharSequence)text);
   }

}
```

}

When I run the emulator, my Main Activity comes up correctly.
[Main Activity of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x1fV.jpg)

When I click on list value of 4140 Instead of bringing up the Second Activity with a tool bar and the textview with the text from my file it stops working.

Also I seem to have left out is that I want to link the text file to a specific list value. When I did this with images, when I clicked a list value my toolbar on the second activity repeated that list value and then depending on what my toolbar said it pulled in the correct image from my drawable file. It seems I am missing that part that will link each list value to its specific and correct text file.

Comment: Is there any Activity object implemented with a ListView UI component? I'm afraid that it will take a lot more than only 1 or 2 lines of code to achieve your objective.

Comment: Yes there is an activity with a list view UI and it's set up with a onclicklistener to bring up a second activity which is where I want to display the text from the file.

Comment: This is just the line of the code on the second activity where I want and the code. I saw a tutorial where they brought images and put them into the drawable directory and then called them and they pulled into an imageview.

Comment: @punisher_malade I edited post to reflect all of my java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second Activity you should use a Reader to get the txt file string.

Check this q&a about [reading a txt and outputing as a textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779607/reading-a-txt-file-and-outputing-as-a-textview-in-android).

About opening an Access database, that's a big topic that will involve a reader and maybe a way to run queries on it. This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180975/how-to-open-ms-access-database-in-android-smartphone) addressed the thing.

P.S.: Sorry for adding just links, but I think they did best explaining each point.

Comment: I guess one thing I am still missing is how do I link the text file to a specific list value. When I did this with images I when I clicked a list value my toolbar on the second activity repeated that list value and then depending on what my toolbar said it pulled in the correct image from my drawable file. It seems I am missing that part that will link each list value to its specific and correct text file.

Comment: In your previous example, you shown that you were passing and receiving an extra parameter named "MaterialName" which we may guess is the name of the thing to read and show. You should still receive it in the second activity to know which file open. There are more questions you should ask yourself: 1) Are those text files local? 2) A database? 3) Are they remote?

Comment: would I still receive it the same way as I was trying in the first place?

Comment: Yes, be sure to send the info in extras as you did too from de first Activity

Comment: I just wanted to say I have gone the database route instead of using a text file. Your links to other questions helped a lot. Thanks